# HTML content layering on top of each other

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Ive added some flip animations (javascirpt) to my grid of images. This has required me to add some extra css to style up the "back" div. The grid of images is now sitting behind the div.instagram element and in front of the footer element. When in responds down all of the divs layer on top of each other.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".success").hide();
  $("form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#wanttoplay").hide();
    $(".success").show();
  });

  $(".successcollab").hide();
  $("form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#collaborate").hide();
    $(".successcollab").show();


  });

  $(document).on("click", ".flip-container", function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('hover');
  });
});
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: Geomanist-Regular;
  src: url('fonts/Geomanist-Regular.otf');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: Geomanist-Bold;
  src: url('fonts/Geomanist-Bold.otf');
}

#header {
  background-color: #000;
  margin-bottom: 70px;
}

#header a {
  color: #fff;
  transition: color 0.5s;
  font-family: 'Geomanist-Bold', helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#header a span {
  color: #ffffff;
  border-bottom: 2px solid;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border-color: transparent;
  transition: border-bottom 0.5s;
}

#header a span:hover {
  color: #7ed321;
  border-color: #7ed321;
}

#header .selected a span {
  color: #7ED321;
}

#header img {
  width: 40px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-top: -15px;
}

#header li {
  margin-left: 30px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.navbar {
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.navbar-header a {
  font-family: 'Geomanist-Bold', helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.navbar-brand {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: 'Geomanist-Bold', helvetica, sans-serif;
  border-bottom: none;
}

.navbar-inverse {
  background-color: #000000;
}

.bottom {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.homepage-main {
  min-height: 570px;
  background-image: url('/images/mainimage.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border-radius: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.vertical-text-main {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -25%);
}

.wheredoweplay {
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.wanttocollaborate {
  padding-top: 30px;
}

.wanttoplay {
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.instagram {
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.instagram h2 {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.container2 {
  position: relative;
  filter: grayscale(0%);
  transition: filter 1s;
}

.container2:hover {
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}

.center {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 88%;
  width: 100%;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: color 1s;
}

.center:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #7ED321;
}

h3.centersmall {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 76%;
  width: 100%;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: color 1s;
}

h3.centersmall:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #7ED321;
}

img.playerpics {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.alextext {
  background-color: #000000;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 30%;
  padding-bottom: 23.5%;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
}

.readmore {
  cursor: pointer;
}

img.theclubpics {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

div.vertical-container {
  height: 570px;
  position: relative;
}

div.vertical-text-para {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -60%);
}

form.formpadding {
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.formmaxwidth input {
  max-width: 400px;
  display: inline-block;
}

textarea.form-control {
  height: auto;
  color: #000;
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 400px;
  border-color: #eee;
  border-radius: 0px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.form-control:focus {
  border-color: #7DC42E;
  box-shadow: none;
}

ul.navtheclub li {
  font-family: 'Geomanist-Bold', helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 40px;
  padding-top: 40px;
}

.breadcrumb .active {
  color: #000000;
}

.textcenter {
  text-align: center;
}

.signoff p {
  font-family: 'Geomanist-Bold', helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.caption p {
  font-family: 'Geomanist-Bold', helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #999;
}

ol.breadcrumb {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  font-family: 'Geomanist-Bold', helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding-left: 0px;
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Geomanist-Bold', helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 50px;
}

h2 {
  font-family: 'Geomanist-Bold', helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 32px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Geomanist-Bold', helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding-top: 70px;
  color: #000;
}

p {
  font-family: 'Geomanist-Regular', helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 28px;
}

.smalltext {
  font-size: 11px;
}

a.link {
  color: #CBCBCB;
  font-family: 'Geomanist-Bold', helvetica, sans-serif;
  transition: color 0.5s;
  border-bottom: 2px solid;
  border-color: transparent;
  transition: border-bottom 0.5s;
}

a.link:hover {
  color: #7ED321;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-color: #7ed321;
}

button.enterDetails {
  font-family: 'Geomanist-Bold', helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  background-color: #7ED321;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 0px;
  min-width: 190px;
  height: 48px;
  transition: background-color 0.5s;
}

button.enterDetails:hover {
  background-color: #7DC42E;
}

button.enterDetails:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

button.enterDetails img {
  padding-left: 3px;
  transform: translate(0px, 0);
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

button.enterDetails:hover img {
  transform: translate(10px, 0);
}

.form-group input {
  font-family: 'Geomanist-Regular', helvetica, sans-serif;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  color: #000;
  height: 48px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  min-width: 240px;
  border-radius: 0px;
}

textarea {
  font-family: 'Geomanist-Regular', helvetica, sans-serif;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  color: #000;
  height: 48px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  min-width: 240px;
  border-radius: 0px;
}

input.form-control:focus {
  border-color: #7DC42E;
  box-shadow: none;
}

input#formGroupExampleInput {
  padding-bottom: 48px;
}

.btn-secondary {
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.btn-secondary img {
  padding-left: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: translate(0px, 0);
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.btn-secondary:hover img {
  transform: translate(10px, 0);
}

.btn-secondary a {
  color: #000000;
  border-bottom: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  transition: color 0.5s;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.btn-secondary a:hover {
  color: #7DC42E;
}

.success {
  padding-top: 60px;
  padding-bottom: 60px;
}

.successcollab {
  padding-top: 60px;
  padding-bottom: 60px;
}

.left-image {
  min-height: 570px;
  background-image: url('../images/nextmatch_image.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.right-image {
  min-height: 570px;
  background-image: url('../images/theplayers_image.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

#homepage-title {
  color: #ffffff;
}

p.shaded {
  color: #ffffff;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  top: 400px;
  padding-right: 40px;
}

p#second-para {
  color: #ffffff;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  top: 450px;
  padding-right: 40px;
}

h2#white-text {
  color: #ffffff;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  top: 410px;
  padding-right: 40px;
}

.vertical-text-main.white {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -25%);
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: -350px;
}

.vertical-text-para h2 {
  margin-top: 0px;
}

a.homepage-top-link-white {
  color: #ffffff;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  top: 500px;
  padding-right: 40px;
}

a.homepage-top-link {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.white-margin {
  margin-left: 0px;
}

#formGroupExampleInput {
  min-height: 100px;
}

#footer {
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: 'Geomanist-Regular', helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 0px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

#footer p {
  font-size: 13px;
}

.dividers {
  padding-top: 10px;
}

#footer img {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  color: #ffffff;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}

#footer img:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.right {
  float: right;
}

.flip-container {
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.flip-container.hover .flipper {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flipper {
  transition: 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  position: relative;
}

.front,
.back {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.front {
  z-index: 2;
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

.back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
  width: 360px;
  height: 371px;
  padding: 100px 20px 0px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@media (max-width: 1199px) {
  .back {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    padding: 50px 20px 0px 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
  #header li {
    margin-left: 0px;
    font-size: 18px;
  }
  .back {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 227px;
    padding: 50px 20px 0px 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 18px;
  }
  .center {
    top: 84%;
  }
  h3.centersmall {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 69%;
    width: 100%;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
    transition: color 1s;
    padding-top: -10px;
  }
  p.playerstats {
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 24px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .center {
    top: 91%;
    font-size: 24px;
  }
  h3.centersmall {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 82%;
    width: 100%;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 24px;
    transition: color 1s;
    padding-top: -10px;
  }
  .form-group input {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
  .flip-container {
    perspective: 1000px;
  }
  .flip-container.hover .flipper {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
  }
  .flipper {
    transition: 0.6s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    position: relative;
  }
  .front,
  .back {
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
  .front {
    z-index: 2;
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }
  .back {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #ffffff;
    width: 737px;
    height: 600px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    padding: 100px 40px 0px 40px;
    text-align: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  p.playerstats {
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 32px;
    padding-right: 40px;
    padding-left: 40px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 400px) {
  .left-image {
    min-height: 570px;
    background-image: url(../images/nextmatch_image.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    margin-right: 15px;
  }
  .right-image {
    min-height: 570px;
    background-image: url(../images/theplayers_image.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-top: 40px;
  }
  .homepage-main {
    min-height: 400px;
    background-image: url(/images/mainimage.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border-radius: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
  }
  .form-club {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  .form-group {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
  }
  textarea.form-control {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  button.enterDetails {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .form-group input {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
  .flip-container {
    perspective: 1000px;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
  }
  .flip-container.hover .flipper {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
  }
  .flipper {
    transition: 0.6s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    position: relative;
  }
  .front,
  .back {
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
  .front {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
    width: 370px;
    height: 382px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }
  .back {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #ffffff;
    width: 370px;
    height: 382px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    padding: 100px 20px 0px 20px;
    text-align: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  h3.centersmall {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 83%;
    width: 100%;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
    transition: color 1s;
    padding-top: -10px;
  }
  .center {
    top: 88%;
    font-size: 18px;
  }
  img.playerpiclast {
    margin-bottom: 400px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="icon" href="/images/favicon.png" sizes="16x16 32x32" type="image/png">
  <title>The players</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/website-css.css">
  <script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/picklesfc.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <header id="header">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
               <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
             </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="/homepage/"><img src="/images/logo.svg" alt="Pickles FC logo">Pickles FC</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="/theclub/"><span>The Club</span></a></li>
            <li class="selected"><a href="/theplayers/"><span>The Players</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="http://picklesmagazine.co.uk/shop/" target="_blank"><span>The Shop</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="/collaborations/"><span>Collaborations</span></a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>


  <div class="container">
    <div class="theplayers row">
      <div class='container2 col-sm-8'>
        <h3 class="center">Alex Stewart</h3>
        <image src="/images/mainprofile_image.jpg" alt="mainprofile_image2.jpg" class="playerpics img-responsive">
      </div>


      <div class="container2 col-sm-4 flip-container" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
        <div class="flipper">
          <div class="front ">
            <h3 class="centersmall">Alex Stewart</h3>
            <image src="/images/profile_image2.jpg" alt="profile_image2.jpg" class="readmore playerpics img-responsive center-block">
          </div>
          <div class="back">
            <p class='playerstats'>Some stats about Alex to go in here. His dad Alastair Stewart is a famous news reader. Alex Stewart plays in goal.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="container2 col-sm-4 flip-container" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
        <div class="flipper">
          <div class="front ">
            <h3 class="centersmall">Alex Stewart</h3>
            <image src="/images/profile_image2.jpg" alt="profile_image2.jpg" class="readmore playerpics img-responsive center-block">
          </div>
          <div class="back">
            <p class='playerstats'>Some stats about Alex to go in here. His dad Alastair Stewart is a famous news reader. Alex Stewart plays in goal.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>



    <div class="row playpicpadding">
      <div class="container2 col-sm-4 flip-container" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
        <div class="flipper">
          <div class="front">
            <h3 class="centersmall">Alex Stewart</h3>
            <image src="/images/profile_image2.jpg" alt="profile_image2.jpg" class="readmore playerpics img-responsive center-block">
          </div>
          <div class="back">
            <p class='playerstats'>Some stats about Alex to go in here. His dad Alastair Stewart is a famous news reader. Alex Stewart plays in goal.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="container2 col-sm-4 flip-container" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
        <div class="flipper">
          <div class="front ">
            <h3 class="centersmall">Alex Stewart</h3>
            <image src="/images/profile_image2.jpg" alt="profile_image2.jpg" class="readmore playerpics img-responsive center-block">
          </div>
          <div class="back">
            <p class='playerstats'>Some stats about Alex to go in here. His dad Alastair Stewart is a famous news reader. Alex Stewart plays in goal.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>



      <div class="container2 col-sm-4 flip-container" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
        <div class="flipper">
          <div class="front ">
            <h3 class="centersmall">Alex Stewart</h3>
            <image src="/images/profile_image2.jpg" alt="profile_image2.jpg" class="readmore playerpics img-responsive center-block">
          </div>
          <div class="back">
            <p class='playerstats'>Some stats about Alex to go in here. His dad Alastair Stewart is a famous news reader. Alex Stewart plays in goal.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="instagram">
      <h2 class="text-center">#picklesmagazine</h2>
      <script src="//apps.elfsight.com/p/platform.js" defer></script>
      <div class="elfsight-app-276db0d4-25a2-4a5e-8a72-30da22fe3732"></div>
    </div>

  </div>





</body>

<footer id="footer">
  <p>© 2017 Pickles Magazine | Football, Design and Wit</p>
  <a href="https://www.facebook.com/picklesmagazine/" target="_blank"><img src="/images/facebook.svg" height="25"></a>
  <a href="https://twitter.com/picklesmagazine" target="_blank"><img src="/images/twitter.svg" height="25"></a>
  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/picklesmagazine/" target="_blank"><img src="/images/instagram.svg" height="25"></a>
</footer>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: So, what is your problem/question?

Comment: all divs.container2 .col-sm-4 .flip-container are sitting behing .instagram and in front of the footer. When the content responds instead of each div appearing above each other they are layered on top?

Comment: may I ask what javascirpt is?

Comment: Whoops spelling mistake... are you able to offer any help? Would be greatly appreciated :)